# How to make a script in javascript that counts the total number of divs clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Like the title says, I'm trying to make a function in Javascript that counts how many divs are clicked A N D tell me which ones were clicked For example:

```
<div>
 <div onclick="somefunction">1</div>
 <div onclick="somefunction">2</div>
 <div onclick="somefunction">3</div>
 <div onclick="somefunction">4</div>
</div>
```

Let's say div 1 and 2 are clicked, how do I make a javascript function that will tell me which divs were clicked (in our case 1 and 2 were) and total number of divs that were clicked?

Comment: When the user clicks on a DIV, add the text content to an array. Then print the array elements and the length of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var divsClicked="divs clicked = ";
var count = 0;
display=document.getElementById('display');
function somefunction(num){
divsClicked = divsClicked + num + ",";
count++;
display.innerHTML=divsClicked + "count =" + count;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div onclick="somefunction(1)">1</div>
 <div onclick="somefunction(2)">2</div>
 <div onclick="somefunction(3)">3</div>
 <div onclick="somefunction(4)">4</div>
</div>
<div id='display'><div>
```

Comment: Thanks DCR, no f***ing idea why this post is downvoted, but thanks for answering bro :)

Comment: it was down voted because you didn't show any code in regards to the javascript. You'll learn faster by trying something, and you'll get more answers if you show some effort in solving the problem yourself.

Comment: oooo, thanks again DCR. I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

To keep track of the amount of clicks, I would declare a public variable that keeps track of the click count and have the function increment it each time it is called.

To check which div is clicked, I would pass the number of the div as a parameter.

HTML:

```
<div onclick="someFunction(1)"> 1 </div>
<br>
<div onclick="someFunction(2)"> 2 </div>
<br>
<div onclick="someFunction(3)"> 3 </div>
<br>
<div onclick="someFunction(4)"> 4 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var clickCount = 0;
    
    function someFunction(divNum)
    {   
        ++clickCount;
        console.log("Clicks: " + clickCount);
        
        switch (divNum)
        {
        case 1:
            console.log("Clicked: " + 1);
            break;
            
        case 2:
            console.log("Clicked: " + 2);
            break;
            
        case 3:
            console.log("Clicked: " + 3);
            break;
            
        case 4:
            console.log("Clicked: " + 4);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just saw that someone already answered your question, hopefully this helps anyway.